# dyld: Library not loaded when Linked in makefile

Tags: c, makefile, dynamic-library

Hi I know there is some other posts with the same title, but they are not in the same context. So: I have a library named `mlx` and the library file is named `libmlx.dylib`: when I try to compile it with a simple main using `gcc main.c libmlx.dylib` it compiles well and the lib is working, but when I try to compile it with my project using my makefile the compilation doesn't throw any error but when I launch the program I get this error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libmlx.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/leo/Documents/42-cursus/so_long/./so_long
  Reason: image not found
[1]    8313 abort      ./so_long
```

Here is my makefile:

```
SHELL =     /bin/sh
NAME =      so_long

.SUFFIXES = .c .o .h .dylib

SRCDIR =    src
INCDIR =    inc
LIBDIR =    lib
OBJDIR =    .obj

SRC =       $(addsuffix $(word 1, $(.SUFFIXES)),\
            $(addprefix exception/,\
                exception\
                bad_alloc\
                invalid_arguments\
                invalid_map\
                runtime_error)\
            $(addprefix parsing/,\
                get_map)\
            $(addprefix rendering/,\
                render_map)\
            $(addprefix utils/,\
                init_image\
                make_color)\
            $(addprefix cleaning/,\
                mlx_clear)\
            $(addprefix get_next_line/,\
                get_next_line\
                get_next_line_utils)\
            main)
INC =       $(addsuffix $(word 3, $(.SUFFIXES)),\
            get_next_line\
            mlx\
            exception\
            so_long)
LIB =       mlx\
            ft
OBJ =       $(SRC:$(word 1, $(.SUFFIXES))=$(word 2, $(.SUFFIXES)))

CC =        gcc
CFLAGS =    -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I $(INCDIR)
LCFLAGS =   $(addprefix -L, $(LIBDIR)) $(addprefix -l, $(lib))

####    COLORS    ####
KNRM =      \x1B[0m
KRED =      \x1B[31m
KGRN =      \x1B[32m
KYEL =      \x1B[33m
KBLU =      \x1B[34m
KMAG =      \x1B[35m
KCYN =      \x1B[36m
KWHT =      \x1B[37m
######################

all: $(OBJDIR) $(NAME)
    @printf "$(KGRN)\`$(NAME)\` is up to date.\n$(KNRM)"

$(OBJDIR):
    @printf "$(KYEL)➤ "
    mkdir -p $@/exception $@/parsing $@/rendering $@/utils $@/cleaning $@/get_next_line
    @printf "$(KNRM)"

$(NAME): $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(OBJ))
    @printf "$(KCYN)[  Linking  ]\n➤ "
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LCFLAGS)
    @printf "$(KNRM)"

$(OBJDIR)/%$(word 2, $(.SUFFIXES)): $(SRCDIR)/%$(word 1, $(.SUFFIXES)) $(addprefix $(INCDIR)/, $(INC))
    @printf "$(KMAG)[  Compiling  ]\n➤ "
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @printf "$(KNRM)"

clean:
    @printf "$(KRED)➤ "
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
    @printf "$(KNRM)"

fclean: clean
    @printf "$(KRED)➤ "
    rm -f $(NAME)
    @printf "$(KNRM)"

re: fclean all
```

I'm linking it with the flags `-L $(LIBDIR) -lmlx`. What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that for dynamic libraries you need to have the `.dylib` in the same directory as your target, I let the post in case some people face the same problem.

Comment: You don't HAVE to do that, but if you don't you have to tell the runtime linker where to find it.  Remember that the difference between a static library and a dynamic library is that the linker resolves the static library at _link_ time so at runtime you don't need the library, while a shared library is resolved at _run_ time so you have to tell the runtime linker where to find it.  You can do this in various ways: that's a whole topic on its own.

Comment: So you have to specify where to find it when you launch the program ? but how to do that?

Comment: As I said, it's a whole other topic.  You can do it at program launch time by setting environment variables.  You can also add options to the link line to give default paths to look in at run time, either absolute paths or paths relative to the program so the program can be relocatable (as long as you copy the library as well).  You are further unfortunate in that you're using MacOS which threw out the traditional handling of shared libraries and did their own, more complicated and harder to use, thing.  Google things like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and `RPATH` for info.